# trying to achieve Rollback with SQLAlchemy, while inserting data in parent-child tables at a time

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, rollback

while using SQL Alchemy trying to implement Rollback functionality having two tables

```
class OrderDetailModel(BaseModel):
    prod_id: int
    price_id: int
    amount: int

class OrderModel(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    order_detail: List[OrderDetailModel] = []

    def create_order(self, db: Session):
    db.begin()
    order_details: OrderDetails = []
    od: OrderDetails = OrderDetails()
    for order in self.order_detail:
        od.prod_id = order.prod_id
        od.price_id = order.price_id
        od.quantity = 1
        od.amount = order.amount
        order_details.append(od)
    print('Order_details list size >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', len(order_details))

    order = Order(unique_order_id=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=10)),
                             order_date=datetime.utcnow().date(),
                             checkout_date=datetime.utcnow().date(),
                             user_id=self.user_id,
                             order_status="FINISHED",
                             order_amount=100,
                             order_details=order_details)

    db.bulk_insert_mappings(order, order_details)    #### if this is used it gives TypeError: 'OrderDetails' object is not iterable
    
# db.add(order) ### if we use this add, it inserts only one Order_Detail
        db.commit()

    return "success"
```

and here is tables script for both tables

```
class Order(Model):
    __tablename__="marketplace_orders"
    id = sa.Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    unique_order_id = sa.Column(sa.String(),  unique=True, nullable=False)
    order_date= sa.Column(types.DateTime, nullable=False)
    checkout_date=sa.Column(types.DateTime, nullable=False)
    user_id = sa.Column(BIGINT, sa.ForeignKey("ums_users.id"), nullable=False)
    order_status=sa.Column(sa.Enum(MarketPlaceOrderStatus), nullable=False)
    order_amount = sa.Column(BIGINT)
    order_details = relationship("OrderDetails", back_populates="order", lazy="dynamic")

class OrderDetails(Model):
    __tablename__="order_details"
    id = sa.Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    order_id=sa.Column(BIGINT, ForeignKey("marketplace_orders.id"), nullable=False)
    prod_id = sa.Column(BIGINT, ForeignKey("products.id"), nullable=False)
    price_id = sa.Column(BIGINT, ForeignKey("prices.id"), nullable=False)
    quantity=sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    amount=sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    order = relationship("Order", back_populates="order_details")
```

I am calling API with following parameters

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "order_detail": [ { "prod_id": 1, "price_id": 3, "amount": 1200 }, { "prod_id": 1, "price_id": 3, "amount": 12233 } ]
}
```

if I use `db.bulk_insert_mappings(order, order_details)`

> TypeError: 'OrderDetails' object is not iterable

and when use   `db.add(order)` it inserts only one `Order_Detail` whereas my example input contains two objects of `Order_Detail`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using `db.add(order)`. The problem you get is not actually related to SQLAlchemy: you're reusing the same `OrderDetails` object in your for loop. If you switch

```py
od: OrderDetails = OrderDetails()
for order in self.order_detail:
    ...
```

to

```py
for order in self.order_detail:
    od: OrderDetails = OrderDetails()
    ...
```

everything should work.

In addition, you don't have to create an empty `OrderDetails` object, you could rewrite your loop as

```py
for order in self.order_detail:
    od = OrderDetails(**order.dict(), amount=1)
    order_details.append(od)
```

or even

```py
order_details = [OrderDetails(**o.dict(), amount=1) for o in self.order_detail]
```